# Cannot list Approvals in Azure using the REST API

Tags: azure, rest, azure-devops, query-string

I'm using the GET [https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/approvals?api-version=7.1-preview.1](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_apis/pipelines/approvals?api-version=7.1-preview.1) call
I know that project and organization is correct, since I'm making other calls that work as expected.
The above call should, according to the documentation list all the approvals, but I'm getting:

> Query for approvals failed. A minimum of one query parameter is required.\r\nParameter name: queryParameters.

I do not know that queryParameters I have to set, since the documentation does not dictate this for listing.
Any ideas out there?

Comment: The documentation is probably wrong. You're using the [query API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/approvalsandchecks/approvals/query?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP), which takes optional parameters with a list of approval IDs. They are probably not actually optional. Or maybe you have to provide the `$expand` parameter *or* the `approvalIds` parameter.

Comment: Can confirm that approvalIds is required

Comment: We should not need approvalIds to list approvals, it does not make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell example based on Kevin Lu-MSFT's answer:

```
$pat="<Your PAT>"
$organization = "<Your Org>"
$project = "<Your Project>"
$buildId="123"
$B64Pat = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes(":$pat"))
$headers = @{ "Authorization" = "Basic $B64Pat"; "Accept" = "application/json"; "Content-Type" = "application/json" }
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/build/builds/$buildId/timeline?api-version=6.0" -Method GET -Headers $headers
$buildTimeline = $response.Content | ConvertFrom-Json
foreach($record in $buildTimeline.records){
    if ($record.type -eq "Checkpoint.Approval") {
        $approvalId = $record.id
        $response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/pipelines/approvals?approvalIds=$approvalId&api-version=7.1-preview.1" -Method GET -Headers $headers
        $approval = $response.Content | ConvertFrom-Json
        Write-Host "ApprovalID=$approvalId and status=$($approval.value[0].status)"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Test with the same Rest API and reproduce the same issue.

You need to add **approvalIds** to the Rest API URL then the API can run successfully.

For example:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/approvals?approvalIds={approvalIds}&api-version=7.1-preview.1
```

To get the approvalid, you can use the Rest API: [Timeline - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/timeline/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}/timeline?api-version=6.0
```

You can get the approvalid in the response.

[image]

> The above call should, according to the documentation list all the approvals,

From your requirement, you need to list all approvals in the project. I am afraid that the Rest API not able to meet your requirement for the time being.

It only supports to return the Approvals defined in the Rest API URL.

Currently, this API is still in the preview status, and some functions may not be perfected.

You can refer to and monitor this feedback ticket with the same question: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-rest-api-specs/issues/557